# Change in time interval in a Poisson distribution when squaring the probability

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, mathematical-modeling

I have a biological process I want to study. We have a bacterial culture in which the probability of one individual getting some specific unwanted mutation is $p$. By a technical process we achieve a way of lowering this probability to $p^2$. This mutation is preferentially selected, so it is a matter of time that virtually all the population has it. We want to estimate how much better is our system with our technical development. For example, we could estimate the time gaining: if the time in which the size of the mutated subpopulation rises to (say) 10% is $T$ when the probability is $p$, which time $T'$ do we get with $p^2$?

I have thought of the following analysis (beware, I am no expert in this!):

We can model the independent, sequential, homogeneous in time bacterial mutations by a Poisson process. Let $N$ be the total population. In a fixed time $t$, if the mean number of mutations in $t$ is $m(t)$, then the probability that a given bacteria will mutate in time $t$ is $p(t)=m(t)/N$ (is this actually sound?). If we now change the time to $kt$, then $m(kt)=km(t)$ (by the properties of the Poisson distribution) and thus $p(kt)=kp(t)$.

Consider now the mean number of mutations for time $t$ corresponding to probability $p(t)^2$, $M(t)=p(t)^2N$. Since we want to estimate the time gain, we will find $k$ such that $M(kt)=m(t)$: $p(kt)^2N=p(t)N$ implies $k^2p^2(t)=p(t)$ and therefore $$k=p(t)^{-1/2}.$$
So if in usual conditions the mutated bacteria are a 1% of the total population in time $T$, then $p(T)=m(T)/N=10^{-2}$ and hence with our technical improvement we get a time of $10T$ to reach the same level of mutations, but the time to arrive at 50% of the population is just $\sqrt{2}$ times the usual time for this to happen.

So it seems that, although the improved culture starts to be "corrupted" way later, its rate of change is higher and arrives at a 100% of corruption at the same time as the usual one. Note that this seems to be at odds with the fact that in a Poisson process the mean is linear with time, but (I think) this apparent paradox is solved by noting that $M$ does not follow a Poisson process (precisely because of our $p^2(t)$ with a Poisson $p(t)$).

a) Is this analysis really correct? Would you do the estimation otherwise?

b) Which distribution studies the time intervals of a cumulative Poisson? How would we apply it to this problem?

Comment: "We have a bacterial culture in which the probability of one individual getting some specific unwanted mutation is $p$." This is annoyingly imprecise. The usual approach is to decide that each individual, independently of the others, gets the mutation during every time interval $(t,t+dt)$ with probability $pdt+o(dt)$ when $dt\to0$, and that what happens in disjoint time intervals is independent. Then each given individual gets the mutation after a random time, exponential with parameter $p$. Furthermore the $k$th mutation appears after an exponential time $M_k$ of parameter $(N-k+1)p$ ...

Comment: ... and you are after $T_u(p)=M_1+M_2+\cdots+M_{uN}$ for $u=10\%$. Thus, $E(T_u(p))=\sum_{k=1}^{uN}1/(p(N+1-k))\sim-\ln(u)/p$ when $N$ is large. Finally, if $u$ is fixed and if one replaces $p$ by $p^2$, then $E(T_u(p))\sim-\ln(u)/p$ is replaced by $E(T_u(p^2))\sim-\ln(u)/p^2$.

Comment: @Did Thank you very much for your commentary, this is what I was looking for. I think you should make it an answer, so I can accept it. The imprecise statement does not come from me, that's why I was trying to make it rigorous! Now the ratio of times is proportional to $p^{-1}$, as it seems intuitively to me it should be. Could you please explain what is inherently wrong in my reasoning, and why? Thank you again.

Comment: @Did It should be $-\log (1-u)$ instead. OP Your parameter is $p$ - probability of getting a disease, I assume, in some fixed time interval (say unit time interval). Then if we use $\lambda$ to denote what Did uses as $p$, we get $e^{-\lambda}=1-p$, in other words $\lambda=-\log(1-p)\approx p$ for small $p$. But in general, you get $ET_u(p)=\frac {-\log (1-u)}{-\log(1-p)}$

Comment: As written explicitely in my comment, $p\cdot dt$ is, up to some $o(dt)$ terms, the probability to get the disease in a small interval of length $dt$. Hence the probability to get the disease in an interval of unit length is $1-e^{-p}$, not $p$. Correcting the $u\to1-u$ confusion, one indeed arrives at  the formula, valid for every $p>0$ and $u$ in $(0,1)$, $$\lim_{N\to\infty}E(T^{(N)}_u(p))=-\ln(1-u)/p.$$

Comment: @Did I read what you wrote, but you used the same variable name $p$ to denote rate/intensity while the OP uses $p$ to denote *probability*. These are two different, though related, concepts and I clarified the difference.

Comment: @A.S. Yes, as is written quite carefully in my first comment.

Comment: @Did Choosing $p$ to denote rate/intensity when the OP uses it to denote *probability* is a bad/confusing choice and defending it in 2 follow-up comments after it was pointed out is even worse.

Comment: @A.S. Thank you, I have seen the difference. $p$ in Did's analysis can be virtually thought as the inverse mean time for $u=e^{-1}$, while in my question it was, as you say, the probability in an interval; thus the ratio of times is different, but both approaches serve me well :) Btw, maybe you could point at the flaw/s in my reasoning?

Comment: Your post is tl;dr but shooting from the hip, I don't see how Poisson process is applicable here. At time $n$, expected proportion of uninfected population is $(1-p)^n$, so by equating it to $1-u$ we *heuristically* get the same answer. Separately, it's somewhat unusual to speak of rate/probability reduction in non-linear terms.